# A GUI which creates and uses a database and installes easily

Tags: c#, c++, database, user-interface

I want to create a GUI with C++ (QT4). The GUI should work on Windows and should be able to

1. create a database
2. use the database created by it (I should use an existing DBMS, in order not to worry for queries)
3. database should be specific to the GUI, other software should not be able to use that database (the database may be for example encoded)
4. the gui with its ability of working with database should be easily installed on the other computers, that is I don't won't to ask user to change some options on his computer manually

So my questions are:

1. What kind of database can help me to do this, what I should learn connected with database to be able to perform this task?
2. Should I encode the database by my GUI, or databases have such command to save them on disk already encoded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try looking into SQLite. The library can be used with C++. It will not need an external DBMS. SQLite is embedded into your application, and you can access you database through it. Also, the database files it produces can be encoded, so it will be accessible to your application only.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should decide what are the scenario your system going to be applied.
then only proceed to source for database provider (MySQL, Postgres, etc).

you can't really jump to UI implementation straight away because all of the database mentioned above can do what you need.

Comment: If user does not have MySQL on his computer, how the GUI that uses MySL can work on his computer?

Comment: your question can be viewed as : "If user does not have N on his computer, how the program that uses N can work on his computer?"

Comment: so the answer to above is simple :
i believe same thing happen to your Qt-based application, where you need to ship the software along with Qt associated libraries.